# TypeScript: Why is this not a type error?

Tags: typescript

I'm trying to understand the degree of type inference at work in TypeScript. In the following code example, why is `foo`'s implementation of `baz.esplode` valid? My understanding is that an empty method matches `void`.

```
interface bar {
    horace: number;
}

interface baz {
    esplode: (string, number) => bool;
}

interface bazzer extends bar, baz { }

var foo: bazzer = {
    horace: 12,
    esplode: function () { }
}

var x = foo.esplode('crackers', 2);
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

thanks for taking a look!

That's actually a bug.  When a function is contextually  typed, we should treat it as though a return type annotation exists that represents the intended return type (per section 4.9 of the language spec), so you're right in that there should be an error.

I already have a fix for this, but can you file a bug on the CodePlex site so our team can track it?  I can push the fix to our develop branch this afternoon.

Thanks again!

Comment: Thanks for responding! Bug filed: http://typescript.codeplex.com/workitem/51 Unsolicited feedback: More annotated examples TypeAnnotations on the typescriptlang.org site would be much appreciated - I'm looking over some of the .d.ts files in the codeplex repo and in the spec, but a collection of examples of interfaces and the functions they model would be much appreciated. Cheers.

Comment: Thanks - I pushed up the fix last night and closed the bug.  Better examples is definitely something we're working on.